# How can I know if pickle.dump() successfully saved the file

Tags: python-3.x, pickle

How can I know if `pickle.dump()` successfully saved the pickle file?
In the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html), I do not see a return value that indicates success or failure.

*I'm working with python 3, and currently in a jupyter notebook*

Comment: If you downvote the question, can you at least say why, or indicate how to improve it?

Comment: why the hate, this is a completely valid question???

Comment: @MattiLyra thanks for the edit.. and the support.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `pickle.dump` or `pickle.dumps` fails an error will be thrown. See the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickle-picklable) further down for what can and can't be pickled. You may also get an `OSError` ([link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#OSError)) if some lower level system call fails

Note however that even if `pickle.dump` does not throw an error, you may still not be able to load the `pickle`d data. It may for instance be the case that an object you `pickle`d uses an import or references a function that was defined in the context of the `pickling` code, say a Jupyter notebook defines a custom function which is referenced by the pickled object. If you now ship that pickled object file to another machine it won't see the function that is referenced in the object and the unpickling will fail.

Similarly if there's an API change in a module that the picled object depends on, the import paths may have changed and the unpickling will again fail.

You may also want to have a look at `dill` which covers slightly more cases than `pickle` https://github.com/uqfoundation/dill